# Need to create the background colour on selecting the table row

Tags: css, uitableview, colors

**Todo :**

- Create the background colour as highlight while selecting the table row using css or any other way

**Current Table HTML :**

```
<table id="ember11999" class="ember-view content-table focus-group ovalview object-table container-view highlighted">
<tbody id="ember12032" class="ember-view body-view container-view">
<tr id="ember12347" class="ember-view content-row body-row-view container-view" tabindex="0" aria-label="">
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

**Tried CSS :**

```
table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row {
    background: #FFFF99 none 0 0 repeat;
}
```

When I tried the above code, the background color is affecting the whole table. But I need to be on the selecting table row only.

Comment: `table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row {
    background: #FFFF99 none 0 0 repeat;
}` is working fine, but if `inspected` class is added then i dont know why its not working, it should be working fine.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekKumar When I'm using the table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row { background: #FFFF99 none 0 0 repeat; }, its affecting the whole table, without clicking the table row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, is this what you wanna achieve?

```css
table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row.inspected:focus {
    background: #FFFF99 none 0 0 repeat;
}
```

```html
<table id="ember11999" class="ember-view content-table focus-group ovalview object-table container-view highlighted">
<tbody id="ember12032" class="ember-view body-view container-view">
<tr id="ember12347" class="ember-view content-row body-row-view container-view inspected" tabindex="0" aria-label="">
<td>Click</td>
<td>me</td>
</tr>
<tr id="ember12347" class="ember-view content-row body-row-view container-view inspected" tabindex="0" aria-label="">
<td>Click</td>
<td>me</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row.inspected {
    background: #FFFF99;
}
```

or

```
table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row.inspected {
    background-color: #FFFF99;
}
```

Comment: When I try the above code. all the table column backgroud color got changed. I need only the selected of which I clicked on the table row.

Comment: @ScottDon are u adding a class to the row on click?

Comment: No. I doesn't adding class to the row on click

Comment: @ScottDon By adding class on click on row, u can target that class directly using CSS

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `tr` doesn't have the `inspected` class which is a part of the css selector.

If it's still not working after you add the class, many times the `td`s have a background (from some css you have), so the its "hiding" the background of the `tr`. Maybe this is also your case.
Change your style to be on the `td`s.

```
table.content-table.ovalview.highlighted tr.content-row.inspected td {
    background: #FFFF99 none 0 0 repeat;
}
```